# What's more correct parent::method() or $this->method() in a child class PHP

Tags: php, class, extend

What's a more correct way to call a parent classes functions? `parent::` or `$this->` ?

```
class base{

    public function get_x(){
        return 'x'; 
    }
}

class child extends base{

    public function __construct(){
        //this?
        $x = parent::get_x();
        //or this?
        $x = $this->get_x();
    } 

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "more correct" synthax because they have their own sense.

`$this->` means "the current object", so if a method is overriden, this is that method you would call.

`parent::` means "the parent's behaviour". It is useful when you override a methode and you want to add something to parent's behaviour.

So, if somewhere in your class `child` you override the get_x method and you want the parent's behaviour only, use parent:: if not, use $this.

I would make an end to this answer by saying it is often advised not to call a *not final method* in a constructor as anyone can redefine the behaviour by extending it.